# PyCharm unable to install ITK package. CMake gives an error

Tags: python, cmake, pycharm, itk

I'm trying to install the ITK package using the built-in terminal. I made sure that both scikit-build and CMake are up to date, as well as pip. 
I'm using Python 3.8, pip version 19.0.3.

When running the command `python -m pip install itk`. This results in a long list of errors and failed attempts.

```
Collecting itk
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/73/77f22a4ce19284e687669424dcfa5f8712bccff7c4521d38fbd6025aef21/itk-5.0.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: itk
  Building wheel for itk (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import s
ys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\s158864\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4l7vqng9\\itk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C
:\\Users\\s158864\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4l7vqng9\\itk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.rea
d().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\pip-wheel-kvu92an4' --python-tag cp38
       cwd: C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk\
  Complete output (92 lines):


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a
 different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/s158864/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4l7vqng9/itk/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 6.3.9600.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.ex
e
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.ex
e -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.
exe
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.
exe -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/s158864/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4l7vqng9/itk/_cmake_test_compile/build
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator - success
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 6.3.9600.
  -- SuperBuild - ITKPythonPackage_WHEEL_NAME:itk
  -- SuperBuild -
  -- SuperBuild - ITK-source-download
  CMake Error at C:/Users/s158864/Documents/Uni/Master/Visualization/2IMV20-Visualization/GeneVisualization/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/sh
are/cmake-3.15/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2410 (message):
    error: could not find git for clone of ITK-source-download
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/s158864/Documents/Uni/Master/Visualization/2IMV20-Visualization/GeneVisualization/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.1
5/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3204 (_ep_add_download_command)
    CMakeLists.txt:95 (ExternalProject_add)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/s158864/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4l7vqng9/itk/_skbuild/win32-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_w
rap.py", line 570, in setup
      env = cmkr.configure(cmake_args,
    File "C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py",
line 221, in configure
      raise SKBuildError(

  An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
    Command:
      "cmake" "C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk" "-G" "Visual Studio 15 2017" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:\Users\
s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk\_skbuild\win32-3.8\cmake-install" "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:\Users\s158864\Documents\U
ni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "-DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.8.0" "-DPYTHON_INCLUDE
_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include" "-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Programs
\Python\Python38-32\libs\python38.lib" "-DSKBUILD:BOOL=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV2
0-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\resources\cmake" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release"
    Source directory:
      C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk
    Working directory:
      C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk\_skbuild\win32-3.8\cmake-build
  Please see CMake's output for more information.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for itk
  Running setup.py clean for itk
Failed to build itk
Installing collected packages: itk
    Running setup.py install for itk ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import
 sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\s158864\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4l7vqng9\\itk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"
'C:\\Users\\s158864\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4l7vqng9\\itk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.r
ead().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\s158864\AppData\
Local\Temp\pip-record-ps6qjmjf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\s158864\Documents\U
ni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\include\site\python3.8\itk'
         cwd: C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk\
    Complete output (92 lines):


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select
 a different build tool.
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/s158864/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4l7vqng9/itk/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 6.3.9600.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.
exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.
exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26729.0
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/c
l.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x86/c
l.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/s158864/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4l7vqng9/itk/_cmake_test_compile/build
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator - success
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 6.3.9600.
    -- SuperBuild - ITKPythonPackage_WHEEL_NAME:itk
    -- SuperBuild -
    -- SuperBuild - ITK-source-download
    CMake Error at C:/Users/s158864/Documents/Uni/Master/Visualization/2IMV20-Visualization/GeneVisualization/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/
share/cmake-3.15/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2410 (message):
      error: could not find git for clone of ITK-source-download
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/s158864/Documents/Uni/Master/Visualization/2IMV20-Visualization/GeneVisualization/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3
.15/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3204 (_ep_add_download_command)
      CMakeLists.txt:95 (ExternalProject_add)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/s158864/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4l7vqng9/itk/_skbuild/win32-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools
_wrap.py", line 570, in setup
        env = cmkr.configure(cmake_args,
      File "C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py"
, line 221, in configure
        raise SKBuildError(

    An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
      Command:
        "cmake" "C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk" "-G" "Visual Studio 15 2017" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:\User
s\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk\_skbuild\win32-3.8\cmake-install" "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:\Users\s158864\Documents
\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "-DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.8.0" "-DPYTHON_INCLU
DE_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include" "-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Progra
ms\Python\Python38-32\libs\python38.lib" "-DSKBUILD:BOOL=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IM
V20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\resources\cmake" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release"
      Source directory:
        C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk
      Working directory:
        C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4l7vqng9\itk\_skbuild\win32-3.8\cmake-build
    Please see CMake's output for more information.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\
Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\s158864\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4l7vqng9\\
itk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\s158864\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4l7vqng9\\itk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'op
en'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --
record 'C:\Users\s158864\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ps6qjmjf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-head
ers 'C:\Users\s158864\Documents\Uni\Master\Visualization\2IMV20-Visualization\GeneVisualization\venv\include\site\python3.8\itk' Check the logs
for full command output.
```

As I'm quite new to coding and can't find any solution/similar problem online I'm stuck. The ITK package is required for me to use with some programming assignments so it is essential that this problem is resolved.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try `pip install itk` ?

Answer (score 0):

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to
>   "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select
>   a  different build tool.

It looks like you need to install [`ninja` build tool](https://ninja-build.org/). Maybe like this: `sudo apt-get install ninja-build`, but the exact command or series of steps depends on your operating system.